# Problemas con fechas españolizadas

Tags: r

Tengo unas fechas en "español" y no logro pasarlas a fecha. No sé si algún paquete lo hace sin tener que reemplazar "ene", "feb" etc...

Los datos son de tipo character.

```
text <- c("01-ene-16","01-jul-20","31-dic-19")

lubridate::dmy(text)
```

> [1] NA  "2020-07-01"  NA

```
parse_date(text, format = "%d-%b-%y",locale = locale("es"))
```

> NA NA NA

Me gustaría obtener 01/01/16  01/07/20  31/12/19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema de las dos funciones es que `ene`, `jul` y `dic` no son coincidentes con las abreviaciones en español, tal como se definen por defecto, para ser abreviaciones les estaría faltando un punto:

```
text <- c("01-ene.-16","01-jul.-20","31-dic.-19")
dmy(text)

[1] "2016-01-01" "2020-07-01" "2019-12-31"
```

Para más referencia de como son las cadenas de fecha en castellano, entre paréntesis las abreviaciones:

```
readr::date_names_lang("es")

<date_names>
Days:   domingo (dom.), lunes (lun.), martes (mar.), miércoles
        (mié.), jueves (jue.), viernes (vie.), sábado (sáb.)
Months: enero (ene.), febrero (feb.), marzo (mar.), abril (abr.),
        mayo (may.), junio (jun.), julio (jul.), agosto
        (ago.), septiembre (sept.), octubre (oct.),
        noviembre (nov.), diciembre (dic.)
AM/PM:  a. m./p. m.
```

Si el formato es siempre el mismo, podrías agregar el punto al final del nombre del mes y luego procesar normalmente con `dmy()`:

```
text <- sub(
  paste0("(.{6})(.*$)"),
  paste0("\\1", "\\.", "\\2"),
  text
)

dmy(text)
[1] "2016-01-01" "2020-07-01" "2019-12-31"
```